# How do you make play again button in libgdx?

Tags: java, button, libgdx, effects

I have a button on my game where it set the screen on my game screen and it's located on my menu screen. So what happens is that when my character dies it just goes back to the menu screen, what I wan't to do is when I lose there will be just a button that will let you play again and a box that shows your score and the best score, I want to know what that box is called, is it just a texture that will show up when a condition is true? and also how do you make those effect where the button or text will go upwards and stop when they are the correct position (or other effects when they show up on the screen).

Comment: I use __Sprite__ for the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it unlikely that when your character dies the game automatically goes to the main menu screen again. It's more likely you are doing some tutorial or took some code that tells the program to go back to the main menu when the character dies.

Anyway, in my latest game I simply had a stack actor as the first actor on my stage. There I would just put in the interface and all like someone normally would. When I need a screen on top I would just add it to the base stack. This could be a pause display with a unpause, restart and exit button. Or this could be a game over screen where scores are calculated with exit and replay buttons.

```
Stage stage;
Stack stack; //scene2D.ui.Stack
Table mainTable;
Table overlayTable;

public GameScreen()
{
  stage = new Stage();
  stack = new Stack();
  mainTable = new Table();
  overlayTable = new overlayTable();

  stage.addActor(stack);
  stack.addActor(mainTable);
  stack.addActor(overlayTable);  
}
```

Now just setup the `mainTable` like you would normally layout your interface/game. The `overlayTable` is used to display stuff overlayed on your main table. I clear it when it's not needed anymore and build it up again when the player pauses or finishes the level. You can also use separate tables for this like `pauzeTable`, `successTable`, `failedTable`, etc. and hide or display these on demand.

For the effects you simply use `Scene2D` `Actions`, `MoveToAction` or `MoveByAction` specifically. You can set a action for each button/actor so you have more control over them individually or just a single MoveToAction for the whole table.

```
Table actionTable = new Table();
    //position the table outside the screen
    actionTable.setPosition(stage.getWidth(), 0); //Position on the right of the stage

    MoveToAction moveAction = new MoveToAction();
    moveAction.setPosition(0, 0); //Move from right side of stage inside the stage
    moveAction.setDuration(.5f); //Duration of this action
    moveAction.setInterpolation(Interpolation.fade); //Fade the movement in and out, many interpolations are supplied by the framework.

    actionTable.addAction(moveAction); //Execute Action.
```

Comment: I have a variable called life( character life) and when it becomes 0 I just do game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game)), same for the play button when clicked game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game)); game is equal to mainclass which extends Game.

Comment: So instead of setting a new screen you can first show a dialog window any way you want. Then add buttons to it that direct to the main menu, next level or to retry the current level to it.